# Filesystem TreeView

Tags: c#, filesystems, explorer

Is there a control that will allow me to click through folders on the FS? Like the left tab after you right click a file and hit explore in explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a control to do this for you, but it's relatively easy with the TreeView control.  Check out [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/RecursivelyloadDirectoryinfointoTreeView.htm).

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking is there a WinForms/WPF **control** that will allow you to do this then the answer is no.  There is no such built-in control that can be used for this purpose.

You can however open up a modal dialog which does this by using the OpenFileDialog.

```
using (var diag = new OpenFileDialog()) {
  var result = diag.ShowDialog();
  var fileName = diag.FileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a library that might be able to help you. You can find it at: http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/

The control you're looking for is the ShellTreeView.